# Android Sensor App acquires extra space after installation

Tags: android, optimization

I have applied android sensor framework in my App. It uses 2 sensors: Light and Accelerometer. The sensors are registered and unregistered properly and the App works fine. The apk file size of the App is approx 5 mb but after installation, I notice the size of the App is doubled to approx 11 mb. How can I optimize the size of this app.?

Answer (score 1):

It's because Android also saves the apk when installing an app, so the size shown = size of installed app + size of saved apk.